# Switch easily between 2 monitors and a TV [Windows 10]

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, tv

Is there a script or something that would help me achieve easy switching between my main 2 monitors and the TV?

I have two monitors that I do most of my work on, and then a TV that I want to occasionally switch to for movie watching or playing certain games.

However, switching to the TV through the Windows 10 settings is a ridiculous chore:

1. Turn on the TV
2. Confirm I want to keep these settings
3. Turn off one monitor
4. Confirm I want to keep these settings
5. Turn off the second monitor
6. Confirm I want to keep these settings

And then of course the same in reverse once I want to go back. With the new settings menu in Windows 10 it's not possible to just queue everything up and set all the monitors and the TV the way I want and only submit the change once, everything happens immediately after you choose the options in the drop down menus for each individual monitor.

Is there an easier way to do this? A batch script for example? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use the three devices together? What are your computer and display adapter models? Which Windows 10 version?

Comment: I don't want them all to be constantly on. The TV is only used occasionally, and when I'm using it, there's no reason for the monitors to be on for hours at a time.

I don't see what the models of the monitors and TV, or Windows 10 version matter, but anyway the monitors are Viewsonic VX3276-2K-MHD and the TV is some Samsung 50'' that I don't know the exact model of. Latest Windows 10 update (20H2).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch between multiple display configurations in Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1322510/switch-between-multiple-display-configurations-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 1):

You may disable or enable monitors through the command line.
You may this way create `.bat` files that will set the monitors to disabled
or enabled as required.

Nirsoft has a couple of utilities that could help:

- [ControlMyMonitor](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/control_my_monitor.html)
  with [examples](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/turn_off_single_monitor_command_line.html)
- [MultiMonitorTool](https://www.nirsoft.net/articles/turn-off-monitor.html)
  with [examples](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html)

These tools behave differently in different configuration of hardware,
so trying is required.

Answer (score 1):

Somebody else asked [a similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1322510/switch-between-multiple-display-configurations-in-windows-10/1516421#1516421) a while ago and was recommended Monitor Switcher. I've been using it for a few days for something similar to what you want (two profiles, one for TV only and one for dual monitor only) and for what it's worth, the switching and hotkeys have worked perfectly for me.